Proof Exercise involving subtrees
Here is a problem from the "Graph Theory" textbook by Diestel.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a set of subtrees of a tree $T$, and $k \in N$.
Show that either $\mathcal{T}$ contains $k$ disjoint trees or there is a set of at most $k-1$ vertices of $\mathcal{T}$ meeting every tree in $\mathcal{T}$

I am struggling to understand what this problem is asking me to show. What does having a set of at most $k-1$ vertices of $\mathcal{T}$ meeting every tree in $\mathcal{T}$ mean?

Think of how the question would be rephrased with k=2

So do I have to show that when there are only k-1 disjoint trees, there are at most k-1 vertices meeting every tree?

To be clearer, you have to show that when there are only $k-1$ disjoint trees, a set of vertices meeting every tree of size no greater than $k-1$ exists.

Let $F$ denote the set of edges $e \in T$ such that the components of $T-e$ contains a tree in $\mathcal{T}$ as a subgraph.
We will prove your statement by induction, before this we must prove that the edges of $F$ form a subtree of $T$ which I leave up to you. Here is the remainder of the proof

 We proceed by induction on $|\mathcal{T}|$. The base case $|\mathcal{T}| = 1$ is trivial. Suppose that $|\mathcal{T}| > 1$. Now for the induction step, let $T'$ denote the subtree of $T$ formed by the edges of $F$. Let $v \in T'$ be a leaf and $uv \in F$ be an edge of $T'$. Then the components of $T - uv$ contain a tree in $\mathcal{T}$ as a subgraph. Let $C_{v}$ be such a component containing $v$. Note that $F$ is maximal (why?), hence all subtrees of $C_{v}$ in $\mathcal{F}$ are rooted at $v$. Let $T_{v}$ denote the set of such subtrees. Let $\mathcal{T}'$ denote the set of subtrees of $T$ we obtain by deleting all trees containing $v$ from $\mathcal{T}$. By our induction hypothesis $\mathcal{T}'$ contains $k-1$ disjoint trees or there is a set of at most $k-2$ vertices of $\mathcal{T}'$ meeting every tree in $\mathcal{T}'$. If we have $k-1$ disjoint subtrees we can take any subtree from $T_{v}$ to be the $k$-th disjoint subtree in $\mathcal{T}$. Otherwise, there is a set of at most $k-2$ vertices of $\mathcal{T}'$ meeting every tree in $\mathcal{T}'$. We can add $v$ to this set of vertices and have at most $k-1$ vertices meeting every tree in $\mathcal{T}$.

If you would like I can add the proof that the edges of $F$ form a subtree of $T$, but it's a good exercise so I suggest you try it.
